# Can I use StackOverflow Careers to find a business partner?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Alright I'm developing a professional RAD application but I'd prefer to sign a contract with a company rather than founding a new one on my own. That company will have to just sell my software and we share the stuff. I develop the software and I don't want the company to do any part of the programming.

Can Stack Overflow Careers help me? If I can't use Stack Overflow Careers, then where can I do this?

Comment: When I read the title, I thought of SO Dating :S

Comment: @WilliamHilsum: why? :D

Answer (score 1):

SO Careers is really not designed for this... And I doubt you will find many takers.

Have you looked at other solutions such as [Reg Now](http://www.regnow.com/)?

I am not endorsing them, but they are the first that come to mind - you will get a much higher percentage and if you only want a partner to sell your products, this (and similar companies) are a **much** better solution.

Comment: The problem is, I can't register my software to protect it by copyright laws. Using these kind of companies is it possible? I live in a banned country :(